# Android ImageButton setColorFilter Not Working

Tags: android, android-imagebutton

I've look for posts that answer this issue, but none of them are working for me, so I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding of just how it's supposed to work. I have an ImageButton which has a png file applied to it. The png is mostly transparent with the exception of a white arrow. I want to tint the arrow red with setColorFilter:

```
imageButton.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255, 225, 0, 0));
```

but this has no affect. I've tried the version of setColorFilter with various Porter-Duff modes, but none of those worked either. Any ideas on what the problem could be or what I might be missing would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to get the Drawable from the button since the setColorFilter you are trying to use (in your setup) apply to those.

```
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) myLayout.findViewByID(R.id.my_button);

int mycolor = getResources().getColor(R.color.best_color);

btn.getDrawable().setColorFilter(mycolor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

As long as you have the correct reference to a Drawable object,

`e.g. textView.getCompoundDrawables()[2].setColorFilter(...);`

which in its xml:

```
<TextView
...
android:drawableLeft="..." 
...
 />
```

you can use myDrawableObject.setColorFilter() to your full liking.

Edit:

For ImageButton, the drawable for `imageButton.getDrawable()` correspond to `android:src="..."` while `imageButton.getBackground()` correspond to the `android:background="..."` property. Make sure you call setColorFilter on the correct drawable.

Comment: This helped a lot, but I had to use PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY - drawable.setColorFilter(Color.argb(225, 225, 0, 0), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);

Comment: Getting the drawable from the view itself worked like a charm.

Comment: Your reminder to make sure I was referencing the correct drawable helped me figure out my problem - I had set my drawable as "background" instead of "src" on my ImageView.

Answer (score 2):

Super late to the party, but just in case anyone else runs into this issue

I've found that if you are creating the ImageView programmatically, use `post()` before setting color filter

**WONT WORK:**

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
imageView.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE);
```

**WILL WORK**

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

imageView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        imageView.setColorFilter(Color.WHITE);
    }
});
```